# AirWatch SDK for Cordova Mobile App - Active Directory and App Tunelling

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, active-directory, airwatch

Our company is building an internal **mobile app** for corporate mobile devices. **AirWatch** is used as an MDM solution.

App would have to access data from internal servers (by calling **Web.API** services). Additionally, each user will have to use their AD (**Active Directory**) accounts to login to the app (*verified against internal AD records*). I envision this can be done through Web.API service as well?

I've researched that for existing applications AirWatch provides "[App Wrapping](https://youtu.be/Np9zCHeN2mA?t=38s)" ([link](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/mobile-application-management/app-development/)), which *supposedly* takes care of **[Authentication](http://www.air-watch.com/differentiators/enterprise-integration/)** & **[App Tunneling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaW1Ehgnkbg)** (*granting access and routing your Mobile App to internal corporate servers using AirWatch VPN*).

However I don't have any info on how to implement this. Has anyone done anything similar? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done it before but according to the AirWatch documentation:

> You can apply available AirWatch SDK and App Wrapping features to your internal applications to integrate your applications and add extra functionality.

Then, just have to implement your app, with or without the SDK but I advise you to integrate it, and upload it on the AirWatch Console. There, you can a procedure to enable App Wrapping and configure options.

Contact your AirWatch administrator to access App Wrapping Guide, Mobile Application Management Guide, AirWatch Software Develpment Kit for Android.